# Can I show progress bar when fetching large meta data from firebase firestore ? Im using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, progress-bar

Is there any way I can show progress bar while fetching large data from firebase firestore ?

Comment: `https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress`. I'm sure you can find one built specifically for vuejs.

Comment: Sure there are many different ways to do that. You should share the code you use for querying Firestore, in order for the community to answer to your question.